# Application user and SQL login

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have develop a web application in MVC4 it is a application about credit and financing. Application is used by 40 to 50 users at a time. Application reporting is very heavy takes 2 to 3 minutes in generating. I am using single db user 'sa'.

Now I am thinking to create all application users in Server 2008 also. Each application user will connect with own db user not with 'sa' user. My question is that is this the right decision?  Will it increase my application performance?  If it is not right then how I can increase its performance? as 40 users taking reports with single 'sa' user may be take more time instead off each user taking with its own database user.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: To answer the question as to why your report is slow, we would need to see how it works and what your input data is. Is it basically just a SQL query that fetches data and renders it? If so then perhaps your query needs tuning. We cannot help without seeing it - so if you could add it to your question, show us the numbers of rows for each involved table, and show us an explain plan from your database, that will help a lot. Perhaps you need some indexes or a query modification.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, while there can be several factors that can affect the performance, using a diff. login for each application user should not affect the performance unless each user's data goes into separate table or partition.

Before actually saying a specific change will improve performance, we will have to see what is the issue that is impacting performance. For ex. what is the size of table, is data pulled by reports causes several joins, is online transactions being run while reports are also pulled, are there any occurrences of deadlocks etc.

One of the starting point for performance improvement is to add appropriate indexes after analyzing queries. However we must remember adding indexes for reports optimization may have negative impact on other areas of application as now the insert / updates to these indexed tables are going to take more time.

Regards

Nilesh